# AngularJS Dependency Injection - Provider from one module unavailable in config of another module

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, config, code-injection, provider

I have an AngularJS application that I'm having dependency injection issues with. Essentially, the application module `conf` contains two submodules `core` and `conf.mods` which are both dependencies on `conf`.

`core` has a `core.components` dependent module, which has a `MenuProvider` provider defined on it. `conf.mods` has a dependent module `conf.mods.dash` which has a config block that needs to inject `MenuProvider`. When everything loads up, I get an "Unknown Provider" error on the conf.mods.dash config block, even when I try to set `core` or `core.components` as a dependency on `conf.mods.dash`.

The source code is in a github [here](https://github.com/mbruning24/angularjsDependencyLoading)

What's curious is that the `MenuProvider` is available during the run block of `conf.mods.dash`, which I guess makes sense. How can I get `MenuProvider` to be available during the config block of `conf.mods.dash`?

If you pull the source, run `npm install`, `bower install` and `gulp` to start the file watch.

Comment: Did you forget to add the files in `index.html` in order?

Comment: if you check the gulpfile, you'll notice that I use angularFilesort gulp plugin. Even so, I've tried rearranging the source files every which way I could think of. Plus, I use concat to a single file, so ordering follows gulp-angular-filesort